# How to see Name of local server when login to SQL Server Management studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, development-environment

Can anyone tell me What is the simplest way to know the Name of local server when login to SQL Server Management studio 2008 for the first time..?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here? If you're trying to ask-and-answer your own question, you're doing it [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If that's not what you're trying to do, I've not a clue.

Comment: well  @Damien_The_Unbeliever  yes of course i asked question.. but  after some time i found the good solution from another source which i tried at my end and it done successfully , so i shared it that may be in future if someone ask this question then it will be easy for him to try this one first..!

Comment: So write a good question that is well structured and describes the *problem*. Then, in the answer box, write your answer. And then (after the 48h delay) accept the answer. That's what *answered questions* are meant to look like on SO.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever alright and thanks to guide

Comment: well i have made changes ..!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried some good way/solution if not anybody found some method he can try this one:

***this works for me fine:***

- First open **RUN** type *services.msc* then go to sql server (name you
  selected during installation ) like sql server (SQLServerExpress) and
  start this application or restart.
- You have to type command **SQLCMD -L** into **CMD** window opening as an 
  administrator & press enter.
- Give appeared server name into sql server management studio 2008
  login box as server name.

[image]